# Syncfusion Report Viewer Does Not Load Data from RDL Report

Tags: javascript, reporting, reportviewer, aspnetboilerplate, syncfusion

I am building an application using the ASP.NET BoilerPlate.

I have tried loading the ReportViewer as per the instructions and tutorial given on the official site. The syncfusion used in making the ReportViewer is in Javascript.
I am trying to load the Sales Order Detail.rdl report.
The Data Sources does not show up

Also tried fixing by adding (Did Not Work for Me)

1) `(processingMode: ej.ReportViewer.ProcessingMode.Remote) in the Script`

2)

```
public void OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptionsreportOption)

    {            

         reportOption.ReportModel.ReportServerCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    }
```

Nothing Worked For me..

Please help me..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqLb4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not reproduced with your shared details. So we have prepared the simple sample to load the RDL file in Report Viewer and it can be downloaded from below location. Could you please confirm whether the below sample is working or not at your end.

**Sample**: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ReportViewer-1236547004

If the issue still persists then could you please revert your sample to validate the mentioned problem and assist you further.